# python selenium - dom - timeout error - search on dropdown

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to open a dropdown and select a specific option, "Unscheduled principal payment".

[Dropdown options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgRMX.png)

[HTML of dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktm2v.png)

There are many dropdowns on the page using the same class so I found the search INPUT. I managed to open the dropdown but when trying to select the item I get a timeout error.

Code:

```
search_field = self.get_search_field()
search_field.find_element(By.XPATH, "following-sibling::button[@class='multi-select-clear']").click()
xpath = f"//following::span//{tag}[contains(text(),'{value}')]"
# xpath = f"//*[contains(@class, 'selectList')]//{tag}[contains(text(),'{value}')]"
self.wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
search_field.send_keys(value)
```

HTML:

```
<div data-v-c3fbf650="" class="checkboxLayer show">
    <div data-v-c3fbf650="" class="helperContainer">
        <div data-v-c3fbf650="" class="line" style="position: relative;">
            <input data-v-c3fbf650="" placeholder="Search..." type="text" class="inputFilter">
            <button data-v-c3fbf650="" type="button" class="multi-select-clear">
                <i data-v-c3fbf650="" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate multi-select-clear-icon material-icons theme--light material-symbols-outlined" size="18" style="font-size: 18px; font-variation-settings: &quot;FILL&quot; 0, &quot;wght&quot; 300, &quot;GRAD&quot; 200, &quot;opsz&quot; 48;">clear</i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-v-c3fbf650="" class="checkBoxContainer">
        <ul data-v-c3fbf650="" class="selectList">
            <li data-v-c3fbf650="" class="selectItem">
                <span data-v-c3fbf650="" class="ml-5"> Scheduled Principal Payment (USD) </span></li>
            <li data-v-c3fbf650="" class="selectItem">
                <span data-v-c3fbf650="" class="ml-5"> Unscheduled Principal Payment (USD) </span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without the definitions for `get_search_field()`, `tag`, and `value` it's hard to know for sure exactly where the problem is in your current code.

Given the HTML you provided, I created new locators and tested that they work. The updated code below should work.

```
value = ' Unscheduled Principal Payment (USD) ' # note the padding spaces at the start and end of the string
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.multi-select-clear"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[.//input[@placeholder='Search...']]//ul//span[text()='{value}']"))).click()
```

Comment: thank you.
i have many search inputs with the same class and the placeholder. 
I wanted to find a way from this WebElement selected,  how to go to the span

Comment: This should take care of the scenario you described in your question. Did it work for you? I tested it against the HTML you provided and it worked for me.

Comment: The thing is that my dropdown is a dynamic content. it seems that when I do elements_list = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath) the element still have not fully loaded so it returns me for element_list.text ['',''] Empty.
I tried everything such as self.wait.until(expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, xpath),value)) but it is still once every 10 times return me empty results

Comment: Are you talking about the contents of the dropdown or something else? The code I wrote should be consistent because it's waiting for specific elements that contain specific text.

Comment: Yes , I was talking about the content item in the drop-down.. do you know why contains(text(), "Text string") returns elements with empty text ?

Comment: No idea. Without access to the page and your original script, there's no way for us to know for sure.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because the element is not found according to xpath. The wait function has a default wait time, something like 20 seconds. More than that will give you an error.
You could try another way, like using the class attribute match, or something

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).